# An old anime with a red haired female main character and a guy with an invisible sword

Tags: slayers

This is an old anime where the main character is a girl with red hair.

- She is able to use fire but quite clumsily I think
- Her sidekick is a blonde guy who uses an invisible sword
- They were collecting some crystal balls or runes that can be put into a sword to manifest the power
- The setting is in the middle ages?
- They usually wear black armor with the girl wearing a red shirt underneath and the guy a blue shirt

Sorry if it's very vague, I can't remember much
thanks

Answer (score 6):

It could be [**Slayers**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/534/Slayers) (1995 anime series)

> Lina Inverse, a wandering sorceress and bandit-killer, joins forces with roving swordsman Gourry Gabriev in what's supposed to be a quick union of convenience. Instead, an artifact Lina "liberated" from a gang of thieves turns out to be the key to the resurrection of the demon lord Shabranigdo. Urged on by the mysterious Red Priest Rezo, the pair has no choice but to fight the dark lord and his servants, accumulating new allies and enemies along the way.

[image]

The red haired girl could be **Lina Inverse** who is a sorceress, while the blonde guy could be **Gourry Gabriev** a wandering swordsman, wielding his family's magical blade, the Sword of Light.